# EOSJS vote producer fails when voting for more than two producers?

Tags: eosjs, voting, scatter

We're trying to use scatter + eosjs for voting. This works fine if you pick one or two producers but any more than that and you get the following 500 error - 
     POST https://api.kylin.alohaeos.com/v1/chain/push_transaction 500

This happens on both kylin and the mainnet. Our call to eosJs is as follows -

```
async function submitVotes(producers, setMessage, setPreviousList) {
userAccountName = ScatterJS.scatter.identity.accounts.filter(account => account.blockchain === "eos")[0].name;
const eosOptions = { expireInSeconds:60 };
const eos = ScatterJS.scatter.eos(env.NETWORK, Eos, eosOptions);

try{
  console.log('account name' + userAccountName);
  console.log('producers' + typeof producers);
  const result = await eos.voteproducer(userAccountName, '', producers);

} catch (error){
  setMessage("Sorry, your vote has failed because : " + error.message);
}
```

}

We are receiving an undefined error in the catch...

The console.logs above give the following (which seems correct) -
[image]

We have also tried changing the proxy argument to "proxy = ''", but that doesn't help.

Clicking on the 500 error gives -

> {"code":500,"message":"Internal Service
>   Error","error":{"code":3010010,"name":"packed_transaction_type_exception","what":"Invalid
>   packed transaction","details":[{"message":"Missing
>   signatures","file":"abi_serializer.hpp","line_number":578,"method":"extract"},{"message":"Failed
>   to deserialize
>   variant","file":"abi_serializer.hpp","line_number":679,"method":"from_variant"},{"message":"Invalid
>   packed
>   transaction","file":"chain_plugin.cpp","line_number":1503,"method":"push_transaction"}]}}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried another API endpoint?  What happens if you try and push the transaction in cleos?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, yes it does work in cleos and we have various other endpoints working using the same version of eosjs.

Answer (score 4):

const sortedBPs = producers.sort();

await eos.voteproducer(userAccountName, proxy, sortedBPs );

...Adding a sort and moving it outside the await fixed the issue.